# $P$(lose 1 dollar)=0.7 $P$(lose 2 dollar)=0.2 $P$(get 10 dollar)=0.1 X:=the profit/lose.

Tags: probability

$P$(lose 1 dollar)=0.7

$P$(lose 2 dollar)=0.2

$P$(get 10 dollar)=0.1

X:=the profit/lose.

$1.$ Find $E[X],\sigma^2$ , is it worth betting ?

$2.$ The player bet 100 times, find the probability he'll lose.

My solution:

$1. E[X]=-1\cdot0.7-2\cdot0.2+10\cdot0.1=-0.1 , E[X^2]=1^2\cdot0.7+2^2\cdot0.2+10^2\cdot0.1=11.5$

$\sigma^2=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=11.5+0.1^2=11.51$

I am really not sure if it is worth it , if $E[X] > 0$ is it worth it ?

$2.$ I need to find $E[X]^{100}$?

Thank you !

Comment: `E[X]>0` means that, in theory, if you do infinite trials, that's what you should expect to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are NOT correct

$$\sigma^2=E[X^2]-E^2[X]=11.5-0.1^2=11.49$$

as already noted, if he plays 100 times,  you can approximate

$$Y=\Sigma_i X_i\dot{\sim}N(-10;1149)$$

thus

$$P(Y<0)=\Phi\left(\frac{10}{\sqrt{1149}}  \right)\approx61.60\%$$

better, using the continuity correction factor

$$P(Y<0)=\Phi\left(\frac{9.5}{\sqrt{1149}}  \right)\approx61.04\%$$

Concluding, if you have to take a decision with these information no, it is not worth betting...

Comment: You multiply $\sigma$ by $100$  then you get $1149$ ?  but how you get $-10$ ?

Comment: @erez: be careful because I  DID not multiply but I summed individual means and variances.

Comment: @erez: $E(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{100})=\underbrace{-0.1-0.1-\dots-0.1}_{\text{100 times}}$

$V(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{100})=\underbrace{11.49+11.49+\dots+11.49}_{\text{100 times}}$

Answer (score 1):

1. Your calculations seems correct. But you cannot answer the question with
   the information at hand. You need to know how the individual trades off
   gains and losses. This is usually (in economics) done by specifying a
   utility function that maps the monetary outcome to a numeric representation
   of the wellbeing of the decision maker. The decision maker is then often
   assumed to maximize the expected utility.
2. I guess you are expected to use the central limit theorem in this case. $%
   X_{100\text{ }}$will be approximately normally distributed with mean $100E[X]
   $ and $\sigma _{100}^{2}=\sigma ^{2}*
   100$.

Comment: Sorry m I cant get how i need to find probability he'll lose after 100 rounds by  $\sigma^2_{100}$

Comment: If you have the mean and variance, and you use the normal distribution approximation, you can calculate how many "standard deviations away from the mean" 0 is (call this value z). The CDF of the standard normal distribution at z then gives the answer.